# Displaying heavy antique wood doors

Tags: drywall, mounting, hanging, antique

I'm trying to display 3 antique wooden doors that I've acquired but not sure the best way to display them. I definitely do not want to drill into the doors.

Optimally I'd just rest them on the floor if I could but each door has a 1" posts that sticks out on one corner which makes them lop-sided. Each door is maybe 20lb and I don't have enough studs in the area to mount all to studs.

I could maybe build a wood base to even out the bottom but then I'm worried the bottom would slide out on my hardwood floors.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:** Not functional as doors. I want them mounted/laying flat on drywall.

[image]

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMjQX.jpg

Comment: So you are looking at decorative, not functional mounting? *i.e.* wallhangings, not doors at thos point in their life?

Comment: **Some more information on the end goal would help to get an informed answer**.  Art on the wall or just against the wall, or functional doors.  ( Or The Doors of perception or a door to a parallel universe, hidden passage ?)

Comment: To clarify, not functional. They'll be used as decorative. Mounted flush on drywall.

Comment: Are you OK with drilling into the back side of the door, the side that is against the wall and will not be seen?  - Do the spaces in the  lattice gridwork in the middle of the door go all the way through? -  Do you just want them leaning against the wall or do you want them mounted ON the wall?

Comment: I'd rather not drill into the door. The lattice gridwork go all the way through, it's 1" front to back. They don't need to be hung. My main goal is getting them not at a slant  (caused by the 1" bottom door peg) and flush standing next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My main goal is getting them not at a slant (caused by the 1" bottom
> door peg) and flush standing next to each other.

Since you do not want to drill of modify them in any way then i would suggest that you make a stand for them to sit in on the floor. The stand would have a **grippy rubber  pad** on the bottom to keep it, and the doors, from sliding on the floor.
It could be made out of some nice dark wood, mahogany or walnut.

The stand could be higher on one side then the other to accommodate the difference created by the nub on the bottom of the door.

Or

It could be a long narrow trough just wide enough for the door to slide into. It should be  deep enough to cover the nub on the bottom of the door. A filler piece of the same height as the nub can placed in the trough,opposite the nub, so that the door sits level.

> Thoughts?

*For a wall mount alternative you could mount wooden dowels on a nice board and mount that board on the wall to studs, that would allow you to slide the door onto the dowels by using a space in the lattice work.*

Deep thoughts by [Jack Handey](https://www.liveabout.com/the-official-deep-thoughts-by-jack-handey-1924315) (man)

Comment: Appreciate the ideas here! Might do a dowel setup. I'm not sure the lattice between each door is spaced for mounting solely into studs but I guess I could do a cross beam between the studs then mount dowels on it.

Answer (score 1):

To use as “real” doors, I’d use a pivot hinge. Pivot hinges are set in the top and bottom of doors, so they would not mare the face of the doors.

I’d use the hinge rated for the heaviest doors. Something similar to this:

https://www.betterbuildinghardware.com/products/pivot-hinge-fritsjurgens-systemone?gclid=CjwKCAiAqJn9BRB0EiwAJ1SztV-DFU2tcIrLUFOshOxARq3x3Cfwoy6-ChMV48ALM-9EQAwDa4XZtxoC0IoQAvD_BwE

Three doors seem like an odd combination for doors, especially as narrow as they seem to be.

Edit:

If the doors are going to be decorative, then perhaps they should be installed (mounted) “on” the wall instead of “in” the wall. That includes mounting a simulated door frame around the doors.

I’d use wood trim, stained to match the doors and framed out all the way around the 3 doors. The trim could mount flush “on” the wall so it appears like a door casing.

Comment: You know the hinge you have linked is rated for doors weighing in at 1,000 lbs...

Comment: @Jack Hmmm...I guess 1,000 lbs. is more than the 20 lbs. the op noted.

Comment: Yup, just a tad overkill

Comment: To clarify, not functional. They'll be used as decorative. Mounted flush on drywall.